# Giraffe and AspNetCore.Identity: Error opening Binary File

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

Although my project starts and works fine, in visual studio code it is constantly stating that I have an error with my module call.

The file looks like

```
module GTest.App
```

but I am getting an error that reads:

```
Error opening binary file 'C:\Users\emoore\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\2.1.11\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.dll': A positive number is required.
Parameter name: capacity //F# Compiler(229)
```

Is anybody aware of what is causing this issue? It does not stop me from developing, but it is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and resolved it by

1. Updating to latest dotnet core 3.1 sdk
2. Updating Giraffe to latest version
3. Be sure to update fsproj file as you won't need to reference the Microsoft.AspNetCore packages anymore

Hope this helps. Unfortunately I'm dealing with a similar issue with NSwag now.